# Root index \sqrt[n]{x} misaligned with libertinust1math

Tags: fonts, libertine, alignment, sqrt

I'm porting all my libertine-based documents to use `\usepackage{libertinust1math}` instead of `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` and a side effect seems to be the misalignment of the *n*-th root symbol:

[image: Misaligned root index: the 3 overlaps the root symbol]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\begin{document}
\[ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}\]
\end{document}
```

I could do a quick workaround with `\sqrt[3\ ]{x}`, but that's not very TeXnical.

How can I make a global adjustment for this spacing and/or should I report this as a bug in `libertinust1math`?

I'm using version 1.0.3 of the package and the [README](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/fonts/libertinust1math/README) doesn't explicitly mention changes to the `\sqrt` spacing, so I'm not sure whether updating the package (which is a bit cumbersome at the moment) would solve this.

Cheers!

Comment: [This picture (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG7YY.png) is what I get from your example with `libertinust1math` version 1.1 (2017/08/16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `libertinust1math` is currently at version 1.1.7 (the `.sty` still bears version number 1.1, though).

The README says

> Changes in version 1.0.5
>
> 1. Adjusted shapes of some glyphs in math extension, leading to better rounding of heights and improved rendering of radicals. (If using latex+dvips+ps2pdf, you should increase the resolution in dvips with the command line option " -D 9000 ".)
> 2. Adjusted left side bearings of radicals so that the index, if present, is placed better.

It seems you have to update; with the current version, your example produces

[image]

Comment: I completely missed this line. Thanks!

Now the point is: in order to use the updated version (Gentoo is still shipping texlive 2017) I should just add this to my $TEXMF directory and it sould be pulled first?

Comment: @EltonCarvalho My usual advice is to install the “vanilla” TUG TeX Live https://www.tug.org/texlive/. I never tried to install it on Gentoo, but it shouldn't be so different from other Linux flavors.

Comment: I added the new package to my local $TEXMFHOME and when compiling it reads from the new version:

    `(/home/eltonfc/.texmf/tex/latex/libertinust1math/tex/libertinust1math.sty`

And this file is labeled version 1.1. I still get the same output, with the overlapping 3.

Comment: @EltonCarvalho You also need to fix the fonts.

Comment: Of course! 

Copying the contents of the `type1` dir of the package to my `$TEXMFHOME/fonts` worked now.

Thanks!